# IE7 not showing SVG contents instead of that its opening the content as an Office document

Tags: internet-explorer-7, svg

Hi I am facing an issue with IE7 browser if i launch any URL with .svg or any page with svg content its asking for file download and trying to open with MS Office.

is ther a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an IE Add-on for this: Adobe SVG Viewer

http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't support SVG.  If you have control of the server, you can try a workaround like [ExplorerCanvas](https://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).  If you have control of the client, you can use pretty much any other browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, ...), or wait for [IE9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/html5-hardware-accelerated-first-ie9-platform-preview-available-for-developers).